# Meteor account-password only returning _id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I already inserted an account through a login form with this data

```
Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $("[name=email]").val();
        var password = $("[name=password]").val();
        var username = $("[name=username]").val();
        var firstname = $("[name=firstname]").val();
        var lastname = $("[name=lastname]").val();
        Meteor.users.insert({
            email: email,
            password: password,
            username: username,
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname
        });
    }
});
```

And since it's just a prototyping, i want to make sure if the data is already inserted or not by running this command on browser console:

```
Meteor.users.find().fetch();
```

But it only fetch the inserted _id instead all of the data that i've inserted to the collection. Is it some kind of meteor account-password security? if so, how can i look up if all the data that already inserted to the collection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243846/meteor-user-returns-only-its-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the answer, visit this link: [Meteor.user() returns only its _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243846/meteor-user-returns-only-its-id)

And this link contain a good information that helped me solve this problem:
http://joshowens.me/the-curious-case-of-the-unknowing-leaky-meteor-security/

I've been busy and haven't check meteorjs for some couple weeks and kinda confused with the new user-accounts package. In case anyone wondering how the user accounts data looks like, this is the user accounts document's reference: http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-user

Answer (score 1):

The users collection is 'special' for good reason, and you can't do a regular insert to it. You need to do something like this:

```
if (Meteor.users.find({ emails: {$elemMatch: {address: email}}}).fetch().length === 0) {
    id = Accounts.createUser({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        username: username, 
        profile: { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname }
    });
```

It looks after doing the password encryption for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this isn't what i need. I just want to fetch the data, not create a new user.

Comment: Right, I see where you were going now. As you probably read, the users collection doesn't return everything unless you tell it to (for security reasons). No worries